# Reorder jquery array starts from the given position

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, slideshow

I have created a slideshow with only 1 img element and several photos so it changes every 6 seconds by getting photos path from a json file
So it send the json paths to a php file and then get paths jquery > ajax after that every 6 seconds change src attr with new path

so i want to add next and previous buttons to the slideshow and i don't know how i only have one idea: reordering the array's elements starts from the previous slide or the next slide 
 like if i clicked previous it gives me previous slide auto and start the slide again with new reordered array
how can i do this idea with jquery

Example:
https://slideshowexamp.000webhostapp.com/

code:
html file

```
<img class="slide"> 
<div>
    <button class="previous">
        <svg>
            <use xlink:href="imgs/icons.svg#chevron-left"></use>
        </svg>
    </button>
    <button class="next">
        <svg>
            <use xlink:href="imgs/icons.svg#chevron-right"></use>
        </svg>
    </button>
</div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        function getSlide(slide = "1") {
            var slides = [];
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'imgs.php',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: {
                    slide: '1'
                },
                success: function(data) {
                    $.each(data, function(index, element) {
                        slides.push(element.path);
                    });

                    slides = slides.toString();
                    slides = slides.split(",");

                    $.each(slides, function(i) {
                        var currentSlide = slides.indexOf(slides[i]);
                        var time = 6000 * currentSlide;
                        setTimeout(function() {
                            $('.slide').attr({
                                'src': slides[i],
                                'slide': currentSlide
                            });
                        }, time);
                    }); 

                    $('.slide').attr('total', (slides.length * 6000));
                }
            });
        }

        getSlide();

        setTimeout(function() {
            var totalTime = $('.slide').attr('total');
            setInterval(function() {
                getSlide();
            }, totalTime);
        }, 1000);
    });
```

php file

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['slide'])) {
        $data = file_get_contents("imgs.json");
        exit($data);
    }
?>
```

json file

```
[
    {   
        "path":"imgs/Slide1.jpg"
    },
    {   
        "path":"imgs/Slide2.jpg"
    },
    {   
        "path":"imgs/Slide3.jpg"
    }
]
```

Hope you understand because my English is so bad :)

Comment: i suggest use this is more easy and very pretty : https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/carousel/#with-captions

Comment: if you prefer create your own carousel this tutorial is your you: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_slideshow

Comment: did a slideshow without json and ajax but three img elements but i want to do my own like with local db

Comment: you can use this how you need in my case i use json this return by a function on django(python), but on other projects i use json and php for this

Comment: Any other suggests?